# MongoDB: distinct of items inside a list across documents

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have my items sitting in a collection as following:

```
{
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "6092037099edca65f29c09d0"
  }, 
  "items": [{"name": "item1"}, {"name": "item2"}, {"name": "item3"}]
}
```

I would like to run a query that returns distinct items across all collections.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Aggregation Framework and Group Operation to get distinct items.

First, get documents with only one item instead of array of items. Then, group these documents by item. You will get as many groups as unique items in the arrays exist. And, finally, project `_id_` field of the groups to the one you need.

Here is an example of Mongo query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: '$items'
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$items"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "item": "$_id"
    }
}
])
```